How to generate the mean of each SOA polygon
I have air pollution data for each different year in shapefile format. I imported each year into QGIS and the shapefiles are in points format and then I added an Esri layer for the air pollution shapefile point layer.
I want to calculate the mean of each SOA point polygon. How can I do that using QGIS?

select all the points in each polygon, sum their values and divide by the number of points.
